# vb.net class and array

Tags: arrays, vb.net, class

I am having an issue with trying to take info from class and putting them into an array with the class data type. I am getting a null error. I can see its not adding the variable info into the array at all. I am unsure what it is I am missing. Can anyone point out to me what it is?

Here is the code:

```
    Option Explicit On
    Option Strict On
    Option Infer Off

    Public Class Form1

Public Class Chandelier
    Private _strFinish As String
    Private _intLights As Integer
    Private _blnCrystal As Boolean
    Private _dblTotal As Double
    Public Property Finish As String
        Get
            Return _strFinish
        End Get
        Set(value As String)
            _strFinish = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Lights As Integer
        Get
            Return _intLights
        End Get
        Set(value As Integer)
            If value > 0 Then
                _intLights = value
            Else
                _intLights = 0
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Crystal As Boolean
        Get
            Return _blnCrystal
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _blnCrystal = value
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Property Total As Double
        Get
            Return _dblTotal
        End Get
        Set(value As Double)
            If value > 0 Then
                _dblTotal = value
            Else
                _dblTotal = 0
            End If
        End Set
    End Property
    Public Sub New()
        _strFinish = Nothing
        _intLights = 0
        _blnCrystal = False
        _dblTotal = 0
    End Sub
    Public Function getCrystal() As Boolean
        Return _blnCrystal
    End Function
    Public Function getPrice() As Double
        Dim crystalPrice As Double
        Dim price As Double
        If _strFinish.Contains("Silver") Then
            price = 39.99
            If getCrystal() = True Then
                crystalPrice = _intLights * 25.5
            Else
                crystalPrice = 0
            End If
            price = price + crystalPrice
        End If
        If _strFinish.Contains("Brass") Then
            price = 49.99
            If getCrystal() = True Then
                crystalPrice = _intLights * 25.5
            Else
                crystalPrice = 0
            End If
            price = price + crystalPrice
        End If
        Return price
    End Function
End Class
Public chandelierStyle(49) As Chandelier
Dim count As Integer = 0
Private Sub btnSubmit_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnSubmit.Click

    Dim ceilingOrnament As New Chandelier

    ceilingOrnament.Finish = cboFinish.SelectedItem.ToString
    Integer.TryParse(cboLights.SelectedItem.ToString, ceilingOrnament.Lights)
    If chkTrimmings.Checked Then
        ceilingOrnament.Crystal = True
    End If
    Dim dblTotal As Double = ceilingOrnament.getPrice()
    ceilingOrnament.Total = dblTotal

    If count <= 49 Then
        'here is where the error starts
        chandelierStyle(count).Finish = ceilingOrnament.Finish
        chandelierStyle(count).Lights = ceilingOrnament.Lights
        chandelierStyle(count).Crystal = ceilingOrnament.Crystal
        chandelierStyle(count).Total = ceilingOrnament.Total
        count += 1
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Why `_strFinish = Nothing` instead of setting it equal to `String.Empty` or `vbNullString`? You cannot do `_strFinish.Contains("Silver")` if the string is `Nothing`.

Comment: Yea I put that in went I first started and didn't change it when I started cleaning it up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just place your dynamic instance into the array, instead of trying to copy each individual field.

Change this:

```
If count <= 49 Then
    'here is where the error starts
    chandelierStyle(count).Finish = ceilingOrnament.Finish
    chandelierStyle(count).Lights = ceilingOrnament.Lights
    chandelierStyle(count).Crystal = ceilingOrnament.Crystal
    chandelierStyle(count).Total = ceilingOrnament.Total
    count += 1
End If
```

To:

```
If count <= 49 Then
    'here is where the error starts
    chandelierStyle(count) = ceilingOrnament
    count += 1
End If
```

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you create your array of 49 elements with this line:

```
Public chandelierStyle(49) As Chandelier
```

but you never actually initialize its contents. What you have is 49 empty slots, not 49 `Chandelier` instances. You need to first set each array slot to a new instance of `Chandelier` before you can update their properties in your button `Click` event.

You can use a `For` loop to initialize each array slot before you use it; something like:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 49
    chandelierStyle(i) = New Chandelier()
Next i
```

You'd have this loop in the constructor of the class (looks like it's a `Form`) that contains your `chandelierStyle` array.

*Note: Don't quote me on that. :)  I haven't used VB.NET for ages and there may be an easier way to do this.*

**Edit**: Or, you can do what Idle_Mind suggested in his answer and just stash the `ceilingOrnament` instance in the appropriate array slot.

Comment: To initialize the contents, you can change the declaration to `Public chandelierStyle() As New Chandelier()(49)`.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman What exactly is the syntax for that? I tried what you have in your comment but that fails with a compiler error. Maybe I'm doing it wrong - haven't used VB for a while.

Comment: Why am I not seeing how to do that?

Comment: @VinceCat What do you mean?

Comment: There used to be a method of declaring an array of objects with a new initializer. It looks like that has be removed.  I'll keep looking for the correct declaration.

Comment: @AdamZuckerman You can initialize an array on a single line but then you have to pass the initial value for each array slot inside `{}`. That'd be 49 `New Chandelier()`-s which is probably less than ideal. :) I think (not 100% sure) that the `For` loop is the best way to do it.

Comment: You can do this: `Dim objCusts() As Customer = { _
    New Customer() With {.Id = 3, .Name = "VB.NET 10.0"}, _
    New Customer() With {.Id = 4, .Name = "VB.NET 11.0"}}` but it isn't the same thing.

Comment: It looks like it was removed before the VB9 spec was finalized in 2008.

Comment: @xxbbcc, actually it would be 50 New Chandelier (that is the way VB does it), but that is a minor issue.

Comment: @xxbbcc how to initialize the array is what i meant. I think i need to initialize each portion of the array, just not clear on the rigjt way to do it.

Comment: @VinceCat I updated my answer with a `For` loop that does that - you need that loop in the constructor of your form (you only need to initialize the array once).

Comment: Yours ideas were great but I ended up using Idle Mind's code, it was short and to the point, Thank you again for your help!